# Is there a second-order conic relaxation method for the bilinear term $z=xy$?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, non-convex-optimization, relaxations, second-order-cone-programming

I hope to find a second-order conic (SOC) relaxation for $z = xy$, but it seems very hard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 3x3 moment matrix is $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & x & y\\x & x^2 & xy\\y & xy & y^2\end{pmatrix}$ which is psd and rank-1. Introduce relaxation variables and your semidefinite relaxation is $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & x & y\\x & X_{20} & X_{11}\\y & X_{11} & X_{02}\end{pmatrix}\succeq 0$ (with $z$ thus being $X_{11}$). For this to be psd, all minors have to be psd, so a necessary condition is (i.e. relaxation)

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & x\\x & X_{20}\end{pmatrix}\succeq 0,\begin{pmatrix} 1 & y\\y & X_{02}\end{pmatrix}\succeq 0, \begin{pmatrix} X_{20} & X_{11}\\X_{11} & X_{02}\end{pmatrix}\succeq 0$$

A 2x2 semidefinite constraint $\begin{pmatrix} a &b\\b & 
c\end{pmatrix}\succeq 0$ can be represented with an SOCP by looking at the minors and after an SOCP representation of the quadratic constraint you have $\left|\left|\begin{matrix}2b\\a-c\end{matrix}\right|\right|\leq a + c, a\geq 0, c\geq 0$

Comment: Nice answer. One thing to note: this relaxation is looser than the SDP relaxation, since it doesn't enforce the constraint that the determinant of the $3 \times 3$ matrix is non-negative. In general we can't enforce $3 \times 3$ SDP constraints using SOCP, as proved by Fawazi [here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10107-018-1233-0). However, since there is a diagonal entry of "1" it *might* (I haven't checked) be possible to do a congruence transform from the moment matrix to one with arrow structure, and then enforce the SDP constraint (see reference 7 in the article I linked).

Comment: Good point, will make that more clear

Comment: Thank you both very much. Your answers inspire me a lot.